# How to translate "Model Name could not be saved".?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have set up rails i18n and it's returning all the messages in spanish except "#{Model Name} could not be saved."

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a quick look @ this [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: Dude
```

In this case, the error would be: `Dude could not be saved`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "The Dude could not be saved." Good to know you can translate model names, too.

Comment: Perhaps should be "The Dude does not abide"?